# How to call ascx delegate to some other ascx btn click?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, delegates

I have ascx suppose A.ascx in which i am writing a delegate on OnInit() like this

```
  btnUpdate.Click += delegate
                               {
                                   if (MaxLength.HasValue && txtText.Text.Length >= MaxLength.Value)
                                   {
                                       lblError.Text = string.Format(Resources.ErrorMessage_FieldLength, MaxLength);
                                       return;
                                   }
                                   if (Update != null) Update(this, EventArgs.Empty);
                               };
```

Now I want to call this delegate on B.ascx btn click

```
protected void btnHdnAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       // How to call above delegate..  

    }
```

Please help me in this

Comment: Excuse me but why do you use web forms server side logic in an mvc project?

Comment: This doesn't look like MVC...

Comment: Is A control contained within B control, or are they just on the same page?

Comment: @Tim Rogers: Control A is in Control B like this i am using the control <%@ Register Src="A.ascx" TagName="A" TagPrefix="Project" %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your delegate a proper method.

```
btnUpdate.Click += delegate { DoUpdate(); }
...

public void DoUpdate()
{
    if (MaxLength.HasValue && txtText.Text.Length >= MaxLength.Value)
    {
       lblError.Text = string.Format(Resources.ErrorMessage_FieldLength, MaxLength);
       return;
    }
    if (Update != null) Update(this, EventArgs.Empty);
}
```

Make sure the Id of your control is set to generate a member for it in the code-behind:

```
<Project:A runat="server" ID="MyBControl"/>
```

Then call it from your B (parent) control:

```
protected void btnHdnAnswer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyBControl.Update();
}
```